# How can i import a function to other file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a function from one file in another one so i dont need to be repeating the code.

***`file.py`***

```py
def getTrain(data):
    trainList = []
    for list in data:
        for train in list['HorarioDetalhe']:
            trainDict = {}
            trainDict['id'] = train['ID']
            trainDict['origin'] = train['EstacaoOrigem']['Nome']
            trainDict['destiny'] = train['EstacaoDestino']['Nome']
            trainDict['operator'] = train['Operador']['Nome']
            trainDict['status'] = train['EstadoComboio']['Nome']
            trainDict['arrivalTime'] = train['HoraChegada']
            trainList.append(trainDict)
        getDelayedCSV(trainList)
        getDeletedCSV(trainList)
```

i want to use the `getDealayedCSV()` and `getDeletedCSV()` in another file since i want the result of these 2 functions.

Comment: if the name of your other file is `foo.py`, just `import foo` then `foo.getDelayedCSV(...)`. This is probably a duplicate

Comment: its not working ... the error is `NameError: name 'trainList' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

`from myfile import getDealayedCSV` or `from myfile import getDeletedCSV` .

If your file name is myfile.py you just have to write myfile .Then you can call your function normally like `getDealayedCSV(trainList)`

Comment: its not working ... the error is `NameError: name 'trainList' is not defined`

Comment: trainlist was an example variable I used. It seems like you didn't define it in your file where you are importing the function from another file.

Comment: i am using trainList in my **file.py** , i can post the code here ... maybe its because i am not returning trainList? and instead i am calling the function `getDelayedCSV(trainList)` like this?

Comment: I think you should post it as a new question now!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57525700/importing-a-function-from-one-file-to-another-gives-me-error
@Kartikeya Sharma