# Importing a function from one file to another gives me error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 files.
One is called **file.py**, and the other is **secondfile.py**.

In **file.py** I currently have the code:

```
def getTrain(data):
    trainList = []
    for list in data:
        for train in list['HorarioDetalhe']:
            trainDict = {}
            trainDict['id'] = train['ID']
            trainDict['origin'] = train['EstacaoOrigem']['Nome']
            trainDict['destiny'] = train['EstacaoDestino']['Nome']
            trainDict['operator'] = train['Operador']['Nome']
            trainDict['status'] = train['EstadoComboio']['Nome']
            trainDict['arrivalTime'] = train['HoraChegada']
            trainList.append(trainDict)
        getDelayedCSV(trainList)

def getDelayedCSV(trainList)
    file = open('delayedTrainsCSV.csv', 'w')
    file.close() #truncate
    header = False #removing headers
    word = 'Atrasado'
    for train in trainList:
       if word in train['status']:
          df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [train['id']],
                                'Origem' : train['origin'],
                                'Destino' : train['destiny'],
                                'Operador' : train['operator'],
                                'Estado' : train['status'],
                                'Chegada' : train['arrivalTime']})
         df.to_csv('delayedTrainsCSV.csv', index = False, mode='a', header = header)
```

Now I want to use **getDelayedCSV()** in **secondfile.py**.
The **secondfile.py** looks like this.

```
from file import *

def counter():
   data = list(getRequest())
   getTrain(data)
   getDelayedCSV(trainList)
```

But when I execute the **secondfile.py**, it gives me an error `NameError: name 'trainList' is not defined`.
Maybe it's because I am not returning trainList, and instead I am calling the function `getDelayedCSV(trainList)` like this?

Comment: `trainList` is a local variable inside the function `getTrain`. So it won't be visible to your script outside that function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `trainList` variable is not defined in secondfile.py and only as a scope in the getTrain function in the first file. Also you should not use `file.py` as a name when you import a file as it is a standard name in python. You should use something like firstfile.py

You should return train list in your `getTrain` function and then

```
from file import *

def counter():
   data = list(getRequest())
   trainList=getTrain(data)
   getDelayedCSV(trainList)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are calling **getDelayedCSV()** in **secondfile.py** as it is potentially already being called in the call to **getTrain()**.

However, the reason you are getting your error is that trainlist only exists in the scope of the function **getTrain** and once this function is called this list will be garbage collected and will no longer exist

One solution would be to return the list from the **getTrain()** function like this:

```
def getTrain(data):
    trainList = []
    for list in data:
        for train in list['HorarioDetalhe']:
            trainDict = {}
            trainDict['id'] = train['ID']
            trainDict['origin'] = train['EstacaoOrigem']['Nome']
            trainDict['destiny'] = train['EstacaoDestino']['Nome']
            trainDict['operator'] = train['Operador']['Nome']
            trainDict['status'] = train['EstadoComboio']['Nome']
            trainDict['arrivalTime'] = train['HoraChegada']
            trainList.append(trainDict)
         getDelayedCSV(trainList)
    return trainList
```

You would then be able to pass this to the **getDelayedCSV()** function in **secondfile.py** like this:

```
from file import *

def counter():
    data = list(getRequest())
    trainList = getTrain(data)
    getDelayedCSV(trainList)
```

Comment: the **getDelayedCSV()** is being called because its receiving the output of **trainList** from **getTrain()**.
with that it worked but how can i print out the **getDelayedCSV(trainList)** function in **secondfile.py** ?

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira ```return``` the datframe in ```getDelayedCSV ``` and add a print statement when you call that function in ```getTrain```

Comment: it worked @KartikeyaSharma but anyways i didnt want to use the dataframe on the **secondfile.py** because i only need until the  __if__ statement in **getDelayed()**
maybe the best thing is to just do the condition in the **secondfile.py**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, trainList exists only in the scope of the getTrain function, you have to return it to use it in counter.